# Plotting multiple Neural Network radial basis functions in one graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, neural-network, surf

I want to plot Neural Nets RBFs in one graph, for example if they have Gaussian distribution. I tried this code for example:

```
figure; hold on
N = 3.0;
x=linspace(-N, N);
y=x;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=(1000/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-(X.^2/2)-(Y.^2/2)));
surf(X,Y,z);
shading interp
axis tight
N = 3.0;
x=linspace(-N, N);
y=x;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=(1000/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-((X-N).^2/2)-((Y-N).^2/2)));
surf(3*X,3*Y,z);
shading interp
axis tight
```

But, it is not plotting what I expect. I have attached the expected outcome to this question. I want to plot multiple identical RBFs with same Gaussian distribution but with different center in the same graph. I would appreciate it if you can help me. Also does anyone have an idea how to plot the other graph also attached to this email which presents fuzzy basis functions.

Neural Nets basis functions:

[image: Neural Nets basis functions]

Fuzzy basis functions:

[image: Fuzzy basis functions]

I tried for the second Gaussian function now with `surf(X,Y,z)` and also with `surf(X-N, Y-N, z)` but I still only see the part of the plot in the limit of `[-N, N]`. I have attached the results. The first is using `surf(X, Y, z)` and the second using `surf(X-N, y-N, z)`:

[image: 1.jpg]

[image: 2.jpg]

**Edit 2:** Now if I add

```
xlim([-6 6])
ylim([-6 6])
```

after surf command, this will be the result:

[3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrGk1.jpg)

Comment: You want surf. Also if you offset something, you add to it, not multiply to it

Comment: Yes, I understand, but still it will show z but in [-3N, 3N]. What I want is to have the plot in for x and y between [-N, N], but show the x and y limits as [-3N, 3N] as I have other Gaussian functions with different mean in the whole figure, as it is shown in the attached photo.

Comment: No, you want the same plot (the same `z`)  in different `x+offset` and `y+offset` positions, nothing else. You just need to make one `z`

Comment: can you check the answer part since I want to add a pic of the result and in comment section that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. Here is how it will be solved:

```
figure; hold on
N = 3.0;
x=linspace(-N, N);
y=x;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=(500/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-(X.^2/2)-(Y.^2/2)));
surf(X,Y,z);
shading interp
axis tight

N = 3.0;
x1=linspace(-2*N, 0);
y1=x1;
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(x1,y1);
z=(500/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-((X1-N).^2/2)-((Y1-N).^2/2)));
z1=(500/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-((X1+N).^2/2)-((Y1+N).^2/2)));

surf(X1,Y1,z);
surf(X1,Y1,z1);

xlim([-6 6])
ylim([-6 6])
shading interp
axis tigh
```

Result in : [4.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSGLj.jpg)